# Express 4.17.1 giving request body undefined have tried many solution

Tags: node.js, express

I've tried many solutions recommended by community and docs. I'm using express js verison 4.17.1 and trying to get request body as shown in code below but its giving me undefined for the body every time I try. Am I missing something?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.text());


app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
   
   console.log("Our body is ",req.body.uname);
   res.send(JSON.stringify({ Hello:" World"}));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port !');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A GET request does not have a body - it only has the URL and any parameters that might be in the URL.  So, `req.body` will just be an empty object on any GET request.

The body would typically be present on a PUT or a POST request and `req.body` would be filled in with some properties if you have properly parsed the body (which it looks like you already have middleware configured to do).

So, it's unclear from your problem statement whether you should be using `app.post(...)` to define a request handler for a POST and then you can read the POST body that can be sent with such a request or if you're just trying to read URL parameters on a GET such as `/somePath?uname=John` which would be in `req.query.uname`, not `req.body.uname`.

Comment: @samiullahkhan - Where'd you go?   Stackoverflow works better if you don't just post and disappear, but rather interact in a timely fashion with people who are trying to help.  Does this answer explain your issue?